# incorrect modalities data in response to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

getting incorrect data from modalities in [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/{id}?$expand=sessions($expand=segments)](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/%7Bid%7D?$expand=sessions($expand=segments)). getting "audio", "videoBasedScreenSharing", "screenSharing" for the participant who did not screen share while "audio","videoBasedScreenSharing" for the one who did.

Comment: 1) Outside of your application, you can repro with POSTMAN/Graph Explorer as well, right? (2) Can you repro the issue without the odata filters as well? (3) Still if you can repro the issue then share the response info (requestid, timestamp)

Comment: 1. yes
2. yes
3. "id": "06aa7258-4986-4f85-8ec6-c9463be96ed7",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-12-18T14:21:49.3279693Z",
    "startDateTime": "2020-12-18T14:14:10.2205324Z",
    "endDateTime": "2020-12-18T14:15:12.1665938Z",

Comment: ok, you can isolate the issue, that's good. If you see this behavior with your subscription, then use tool like NGROK to see what you notice in it.

Comment: Requestid, timestamp will be returned as part of our Graph response - share it.

Comment: already shared the id and timestamp. not sure what to do with ngrok

Comment: Can you guide me on what to do with ngrok here?

Comment: You can get started how you can [debug with NGROK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-channel-ngrok?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: What's the purpose of using ngrok n my context. What are we trying to debug. I am getting correct the full response. The issue is that the modalities are coming incorrect.

Comment: any updates please. really stuck here.

Comment: We are checking internally regarding the issue you are facing and get back to you soon.

Comment: kindly help as its still not resolved

Comment: Hi @PankajMathur, could you please share the call record id for a call that happened within the past 30 days to look up the call.